# Getting Docker to run on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-network

When trying to build a docker container on my raspberry pi 3, I encountered this error

```
 ---> Running in adfb8905587b
failed to create endpoint amazing_hamilton on network bridge: failed to add the host (vetha45fbc5) <=> sandbox (veth7714d12) pair interfaces: operation not supported
```

I was able to find someone else with the same issue [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080846/docker-on-ubuntu-server-rasberry-pi-failed-to-create-endpoint-on-network-bridg), and their solution was that we're missing the "Raspberry Pi Linux kernel extra modules" and to install it with these command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

I've found that this command does not work for me, and returns the following error

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-raspi
```

How can I resolve this issue and get docker running on my Raspberry Pi 3?

Comment: what distro are you using on rpi? ubuntu server like the other OP? I used `Raspbian` in the past and had no issues, it worked pretty well.

Comment: @JuanFontes Also running on raspbian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kernel update will do the job, simply call:
sudo rpi-update